# How do I align the decimal point when displaying doubles and floats

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

If I have the following decimal point numbers:

```
Double[] numbers = new Double[] {1.1233, 12.4231414, 0.123, 123.3444, 1.1};
for (Double number : numbers) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%4.3f", number));
}
```

Then I get the following output:

```
1.123
12.423
0.123
123.344
1.100
```

What I want is:

```
   1.123
  12.423
   0.123
 123.344
   1.100
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The part that can be a bit confusing is that `String.format("4.3", number)`

the `4` represents the length of the entire number(including the decimal), not just the part preceding the decimal.  The `3` represents the number of decimals.

So to get the format correct with up to 4 numbers before the decimal and 3 decimal places the format needed is actually `String.format("%8.3f", number)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that prints spaces before the number.

If they are all going to be `4.3f`, we can assume that each number will take up to 8 characters, so we can do that:

```
public static String printDouble(Double number)
{
  String numberString = String.format("%4.3f", number);
  int empty = 8 - numberString.length();
  String emptyString = new String(new char[empty]).replace('\0', ' ');

  return (emptyString + numberString);
}
```

Input:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(printDouble(1.123));
    System.out.println(printDouble(12.423));
    System.out.println(printDouble(0.123));
    System.out.println(printDouble(123.344));
    System.out.println(printDouble(1.100));
}
```

Output:

```
run:
   1,123
  12,423
   0,123
 123,344
   1,100
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simple method, user System.out.printf();

```
Double[] numbers = new Double[]{1.1233, 12.4231414, 0.123, 123.3444, 1.1};

for (Double number : numbers) {
  System.out.printf("%7.3f\n", number);
}
```

Comment: It's actually `%8.3f`, at least on my computer.

Comment: It depends on the output format length I think, `123.344` its length is about 7, it's the minimum you should reserve in your printf format.

Comment: I think the first number means the total of characters to use, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, something like that, I also have the same thought.